Ubuntu 24.04 - how to set specific programs to open maximized by default?
In Ubuntu 22.04, most apps (particularly Slack) opened as maximized by default. On 24.04, Slack opens only on the middle part of the screen. How can I make selected apps open as maximized by default?
Maximized by default GNOME extension would open all apps as maximized by default. I want only selected apps to do so, e.g. Slack - yes, terminal - no.
EDIT: Slack and some other apps do not have an explicit setting to do this in-app, that's why I'm looking for general Ubuntu solution.

I just learn a program devilspie2 from this question, and think this should suits your need.
First, install devilspie2
sudo apt update && sudo apt install devilspie2 -y

Then, write your scripts for your apps which want to maximize when open; I've tested by myself to match Slack. To debug, you can run with devilspie2 -d to see debug_print. Please do read README - less /usr/share/doc/devilspie2/README.gz, might be chatgpt can help you, if you not very good at scripting.
mkdir -p ~/.config/devilspie2
## below is an example script, which can be pasted to terminal 
## and create it as ~/.config/devilspie2/max_my_loved.lua
cat > ~/.config/devilspie2/max_my_loved.lua << \EOF
if (get_window_type() == "WINDOW_TYPE_NORMAL" and not string.match(get_window_property("_NET_WM_STATE"),"_NET_WM_STATE_SKIP_PAGER") ) then
  -- uncomment below line with devilspie2 -d, you can catch
  -- all windows' name
  -- debug_print('catch windows: ' .. get_application_name());
  if string.find(get_application_name(), "Slack") then
    debug_print("Maximize: " .. get_application_name());
    maximize();
  end
end
EOF

### then run devilspie2, you can test its effect.
devilspie2

Oh, don't forget to put devilspie2 to your startup applications list.

Could you please share your example with slack? Cause I don't really understand how you are catching that the current window is slack..

Ok, I update my example script, you can uncomment the line I add with debug_print, and using devilspie2 -d, you can see all current app name in console ouput - those lines started with catch windows: ; From my understanding, devilspie2 will iterate all created windows, and run this lua script. So if the string.find() function match, maximize() will maximize the matched window for you. @Yehor

Thank you, Alfred!

Also as a workaround, which helped me:

manually resize the window to full size (without clicking maximize button)
some windows on ubuntu 24 don't have resizing cursor, but you can resize them by pressing WIN key + holding MiddleButton mouse click

Then for me all the windows, resized in this way keep their size and position on close-open
